# how to change location of the plugins & wordpress themes folder

Tags: plugins, themes

how to change location of the plugins & wordpress themes folder I am waiting for reply and in which file changes required also mention please....

Comment: There are many answer for your question on our site. Please use the search.

Comment: You were lucky and there's a very good answer down here, but please try to ask better the next time: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can't move only those folders.

You can [move the plugins folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_plugin_folder) in the `wp-config.php` file:

Quoted text from WordPress Codex:

> Set WP_PLUGIN_DIR to the full local path of this directory (no
>   trailing slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
> ```

OR:

> Set WP_PLUGIN_URL to the full URI of this directory (no trailing
>   slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
> ```

Quoted text from WordPress Codex:

> If you have compability issues with plugins Set PLUGINDIR to the full
>   local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'PLUGINDIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
> ```

---

**NOTE:** This stuff changes over time and this is an advanced setting. [Read the entire linked page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) before editing and follow the examples set there. Not the one here which may eventually be out of date.

---

You can [move the entire `wp-content` folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder) (plugins, themes, uploads, etc.).

Quoted text from WordPress Codex:

> Set WP_CONTENT_DIR to the full local path of this directory (no
>   trailing slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/blog/wp-content' );
> ```

OR:

> Set WP_CONTENT_URL to the full URI of this directory (no trailing
>   slash), e.g.
>
> ```
> define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content' );
> ```

---

**NOTE:** This stuff changes over time and this is an advanced setting. [Read the entire linked page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) before editing and follow the examples set there. Not the one here which may eventually be out of date.

---

Comment: We can set the whole wp-content to be elsewhere too.

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo . I pasted wrong. Look past the first **NOTE:** block.

Comment: Wouldn't it be advisable to also set FTP_CONTENT_DIR, FTP_PLUGIN_DIR accordingly (with respect to updates) ?